# How to correctly implement a Timer in a Simon says Game in Java

Tags: java

I'm creating a simon says program that is intended to print a Color briefly then print empty lines repeatedly. The player then has to type the to make it more of a memory game. I can't get the timer correctly implemented without errors. errors mostly occur with the code not recognizing the call to the timer method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class SimonSays {
   
        public void timer(int seconds) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new CancelTask(), seconds*1000);
    }

    class CancelTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            for(int t = 0; t < 4; t++){
                System.out.println(Colors.get(t));
            }
            timer.cancel(); //Terminate the timer thread
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> Colors = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> guesses = new ArrayList<String>();
        Timer timer; 
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int k = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
        if (k == 0) {
            Colors.add("Red");
            }
            if (k == 1) {
            Colors.add("Blue");
            }
            if (k == 2) {
            Colors.add("Yellow");
            }
            if (k == 3) {
            Colors.add("Green");
            }
    
    }
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int r = 0; r<4;r++){
        System.out.println(Colors.get(r)); 
        new timer(1);
     for(int f = 0; f < 40; f++){
        System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
    
    for(int g = 0; g < 4; g++) {
        String guess = input.nextLine();
        guesses.add(guess);
    }
    
    if (guesses.equals(Colors)) {
        System.out.println("Well done!");
        input.close();
     }
    else {
        System.out.println("Not correct! You lose!");
        input.close(); 
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do some debugging work to narrow down your issue before posting here. Also, as their Javadoc notes, the `Timer` and `TimerTask` classes are legacy. Supplanted by the executor framework way back in Java 5.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Thread.sleep` instead of `TimerTask`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimonSays {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<String> colors = Arrays.asList("Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green");
        Collections.shuffle(colors);
        printColors(colors, 1);
        List<String> guesses = getGuesses(colors.size());
        if (guesses.equals(colors)) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations you remembered correctly ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not correct, you lose ");
            System.out.printf("You guessed: %s%n", String.join(", ", guesses));
            System.out.printf("The correct order was: %s%n", String.join(", ", colors));
        }
    }

    private static List<String> getGuesses(int numColors) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> guesses = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= numColors; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter color %d (case-sensitive): ", i);
            guesses.add(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        return guesses;
    }

    private static void printColors(List<String> colors, long seconds) throws InterruptedException {
        for (String color : colors) {
            System.out.println(System.lineSeparator().repeat(50));
            System.out.println(color);
            Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
        }
        System.out.println(System.lineSeparator().repeat(50));
    }

}
```

**Example Usage Win:**

```
Enter color 1 (case-sensitive): Red
Enter color 2 (case-sensitive): Blue
Enter color 3 (case-sensitive): Yellow
Enter color 4 (case-sensitive): Green
Congratulations you remembered correctly
```

**Example Usage Loss:**

```
Enter color 1 (case-sensitive): Blue
Enter color 2 (case-sensitive): Red
Enter color 3 (case-sensitive): Yellow
Enter color 4 (case-sensitive): Green
Not correct, you lose 
You guessed: Blue, Red, Yellow, Green
The correct order was: Green, Yellow, Blue, Red
```